# How to format decimal space using awk in linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk

original file :

```
a|||a 2 0.111111
a|||book 1 0.0555556
a|||is 2 0.111111
```

now i need to control third columns with 6 decimal space

after i tried   `awk {'print $1,$2; printf "%.6f\t",$3'}`
but the output is not what I want

result :

```
a|||a 2
0.111111        a|||book 1
0.055556        a|||is 2
```

that's weird , how can I do that will just modify third columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `print()` is adding a newline character. Include your third field inside it, but formatted. Try with `sprintf()` function, like:

```
awk '{print $1,$2, sprintf("%.6f", $3)}' infile
```

That yields:

```
a|||a 2 0.111111
a|||book 1 0.055556
a|||is 2 0.111111
```

Answer (score 1):

Print adds a newline on the end of printed strings, whereas printf by default doesn't. This means a newline is added after every second field and none is added after the third.

You can use printf for the whole string and manually add a newline.

Also I'm not sure why you are adding a tab to the end of the lines, so i removed that

```
awk '{printf "%s %d %.6f\n",$1,$2,$3}' file

a|||a 2 0.111111
a|||book 1 0.055556
a|||is 2 0.111111
```